# Flask create users in database from bootstrap login template?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm new to Flask. I've used [this bootstrap login](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/) template for my page, however, I am unsure of how to proceed. How to I make the user input store it and redirect it on to the following authorized page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access request data via the [`flask.request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.request) object:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@users.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    // show the login form for a GET request
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signin.html')
    // validate user credentials for a POST request (form submit)
    else:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        // validate user and set a cookie or something
        // ...
        return render_template('authorized_area.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But you may want to consider using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org). It handles user authentication for you so that you can restrict access to routes by using the `@login_required` decorator.

See this [Tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/introduction-to-flask-part-2-creating-a-login-page/) for a simple example using Flask and Bootstrap. It also explains how to access request data.

There are many good flask tutorials out there. [The Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) explains each step of developing a web application with flask in great detail.